# How can I download a file with PHP or HTML?

Tags: php, html, file, xhtml, download

I am making a file hosting website and am about 95% done but have one issue. When the user clicks their file to download it, the file just appears in the browser. I need to know a way where I can define the `$file` variable in the `while` loop to be downloadable. The variable that I need to make downloadable is surrounded by asterisks(*)

LOOP:

```
$directory = 'uploads/' . $_SESSION['user'] . '/';

    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    echo '<h3>Your files are listed below</h3>';    

    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        echo '<a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'">' . *$file*.'<br>';    
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the file type?

Comment: The file type will vary, as it is a file hosting service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will performs on onclick, with confirmation alert box,

```
<?php

$directory = 'uploads/' . $_SESSION['user'] . '/';

if(isset($_REQUEST['DelFile'])) {
    $DeleteFile = $_REQUEST['DelFile'];
    if(file_exists($directory.$DeleteFile)) {
        @unlink($directory.$DeleteFile);
        header("location:SamePageURL.php?msg=1");
    } else header("location:SamePageURL.php?msg=2");
}

if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
echo '<h3>Your files are listed below</h3>';    
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'">' . $file.' <a href="javascript:deletedata('.$file.')>Delete</a> <br>';  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) {
    $Message = $_REQUEST['msg'];
    if($Message == 1) echo "File deleted sucessfully";
    else if($Message == 1) echo "File not found";
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">function deletedata(FileName){if(window.confirm("Wish to Delete (Press OK) or Cancel"))  window.location="SamePageURL.php?DelFile="+FileName;}</script>
```

Comment: Make sure to place javascript in header tag of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Usually every non-text file is downloaded automatically. For textfiles, you need to specify the header at the beginning of your script:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
```

Comment: true, forgot about that, try the header tag and specify the filename. This works, ill used it together with xml so i can download them and it worked.

Comment: Can you provide a example please? I am new to PHP

Comment: Well, the file you have to download is named "file.jpg". You just specify at the beginning of the script following line: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.jpg");` Ofc you have to create a dynamic filename via a variable, but i dont know your code and cant give you that much advices abotu it.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is header, check the link for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Answer (score 0):

You need redirect your users to a second script to handle request:

download.php?file=somepath/somefile.ext

```
<?php
$file_url = $_GET['file'];
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
?>
```

Your link will be:

```
echo '<a href="download.php?file='.$directory.'/'.$file.'">' . $file.'<br>';
```

Comment: Where do I put the first part?

Comment: In the second file **download.php**

Comment: So then just `include()` the download.php?

Comment: Nope! you need to have two files separated, in your first file, your link will point to **download.php?file=...**

Comment: Can you provide a example?

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTING_SERVER\interface.php:49) in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTING_SERVER\interface.php on line 80

Warning: readfile() [function.readfile]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTING_SERVER\interface.php on line 81

Comment: You need check your path... can you put your html source code of your fist file? http://pastebin.com/

Comment: You need update your href attrib **echo '<a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'">' . $file.'<br>';** please see my response

Comment: You need update your HREF, please see my response. You will have **echo '<a href="download.php?file='.$directory.'/'.$file.'">' . $file.'<br>';** <---- add download.php?file= at the start

Comment: The start of what part, I am not understanding where

Comment: echo '<a href=" HERE!!!!!! download.php?file='.$directory.'/'.$file.'">' . $file.'<br>';

Comment: Ok, please, update your question, add the full php code, and past your current error.