# How to delete files in a directory with PHP on a file hosting site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xhtml, directory

I am trying to make a simple file hosting site for my family, a couple friends and I to use. I have the entire system setup except one thing... I cannot find a way to let the user delete a file without having to access the FTP. I will post the code in which I use  to list the files to the user below. I want to have a delete button automatically generated for each new file the user uploads.

Code to list files:

```
$directory = 'uploads/' . $_SESSION['user'] . '/';
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    echo '<h3>Your files are listed below</h3>';    
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $directory . '/' . $file . '">' . $file . '<br>';    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$directory = 'uploads/' . $_SESSION['user'] . '/';

if(isset($_REQUEST['DelFile'])) {
    $DeleteFile = $_REQUEST['DelFile'];
    if(file_exists($directory.$DeleteFile)) {
        @unlink($directory.$DeleteFile);
        header("location:SamePageURL.php?msg=1");
    } else header("location:SamePageURL.php?msg=2");
}

if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
echo '<h3>Your files are listed below</h3>';    
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'">' . $file.' <a href="SamePageURL.php?DelFile='.$file.'">Delete</a> <br>';  
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])) {
    $Message = $_REQUEST['msg'];
    if($Message == 1) echo "File deleted sucessfully";
    else if($Message == 1) echo "File not found";
}
```

Comment: replace SamePageURL.php with your PHP page name.

Comment: Now I get cannot modify header

Comment: Nevermind, I can just turn the error off for that part. Thanks

Comment: OK... refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793482/php-error-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent?rq=1. use ob_start() at top of your page.

Comment: You were fast at answering this, Do you think you could take a look at another question I had. I want to download the file on click: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605867/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-php-or-html

Comment: Will not download upon clicking the file name

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unlink()` php function

Ref: http://www.php.net/unlink

```
<?php
   $mask = "*.jpg"
  array_map( "unlink", glob( $mask ) );
?>
```

Comment: I tried that but it does not link to any file, as I am listing the files with the `while` loop

Comment: Make sure you have neccessary permissions to delete the file

Comment: I have all the permissions, It is that it does not know the file type or any informaion about the file in general. Remember the user is able to upload any file they want.

Comment: It doesn't need to know anything about the file type other than it's exact path and it's name.

Comment: if you have the permissions then `unlink` will work. if it doesn't then something else is is awry